# Reactor not honoring runOn after flatMap call

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

I am using the SpringData MongoDB Reactive Streams driver with code that does something like this:

```java
reactiveMongoOperations.changeStream(changeStreamOptions, MyObject.class)
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.newParallel("my-scheduler", 4))
    .map(ChangeStreamEvent::getBody)
    .flatMap(o -> {
        reactiveMongoOperations.findAndModify(query, update, options, MyObject.class)
    })
    .subscribe(this::process)
```

I would expected everything to execute in `my-scheduler`. What actually happens is that the `flatMap` operation does execute in `my-scheduler`, while the code in my `process()` method does not.

Can someone please explain why this is so - is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? How can I get all the operations defined in the `Flux` to execute on the same scheduler?

Comment: what thread does the `process` execute in? could it be that the mongo driver changes the threads in `findAndModify`?

Comment: @SimonBaslé, the `process` method executes in a generic thread ("Thread-nn"). If I add *another* `runOn()` after the `flatMap()` call then `process` will execute in `my-scheduler`. I don't think I should need to do that though.

Answer (score 0):

`runOn()` specifies the scheduler which is used to run each "rail" of the parallel thread. It doesn't effect subscribers.

If you want to specify a scheduler for subscribers, then you should specify that using [`subscribeOn()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#subscribeOn-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-) on the original `Flux` (before the `parallel()` call.)